# Setting a blank custom header in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers

I'm writing a REST server using Ruby on rails.

Some of the communication with the client is by setting certain custom headers to predefined values.  In certain situations the server is expected to respond with a custom header that is an empty string. My problem is that rails seems to omit any blank headers from the response (it will even omit a whitespace header).

This is my current code:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'X-WOPI-EmptyLock' => "",
  'X-WOPI-FullLock' => "astring",
  'Random-header' => "with value",
  'Random-empty-header' => ""
}
```

But the response will only contain headers which are not empty strings:

[Resulting headers in response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C4LK.png)
[Curl response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg0Hh.png)

Is there some way to configure rails to still send headers even if they are empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `custom headers` in `config/application.rb` file

Ex:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'Custom-Header1' => "", # without value
  'Custom-Header2' => "with value"
}
```

**Note:** restart rails server after made changes

In response

```
Custome-Header1 →
Custome-Header2 →with value
```

**Updated answer**

Here is my `controller code` as below

```
 def home

    response.headers["My-Custome-Header"] = "With value"
    response.headers["My-Custome-Header-2"] = "" # Without value

    render json: {data: "It's working my friend"}
  end
```

And required output as shown in screenshot

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it unfortunately does not work. Custom-Header2 is added, but the response still does not contain Custom-Header1.

Comment: where you see the header is not set?

Comment: I've checked headers with the Firefox build in tools, RESTClient (Firefox), Advanced REST client (Chrome app) and curl. In all cases an empty header is not seen.

Comment: Will you pls add the screenshot for the same

Comment: Because it's working fine for me, I think you are checking on wrong place

Comment: Edited my question, so it contains a screenshot of the result.

Comment: It's seems latest versions of browsers are `opt-out` the `blank headers`, but you can use it programatically in `rails code` wherever you want to.

Comment: It's not just browsers - I've attached a screenshot of the headers from curl, and it is also missing the empty string headers.

Comment: Yes, I see, BTW what you need to do with blank header?

Comment: Microsoft WOPI identifies unlocked files by sending an empty lock header when the user ties to unlock an unlocked file.